# How to setup an external developer for Access 365 Web App

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, ms-access-2013

Owner has a Sharepoint site and wants to host an Access 365 Web App on it.
How should the owner setup a new Access 365 Web App so he could hire one or more external developers later, so they would be able to access that Web App and do some additions? All kinds of additions - creating new Access objects, writing VBA code, accessing data records.

Answer (score 0):

He just need to create users for these developers so they will be able to use o365 services including debugging, deploying apps on the tenant.